# Ember Sort Models

Tags: arrays, sorting, ember.js

Hi I have an array of models(images) which is the model property of an ArrayController.

I want to be able to sort the the array such that when click on the image it automatically moves itself to a predefined index. (E.g. when I click an item on the array it should move to middle of the array) and the UI is updated to reflect the new position.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vesakafaca/1/edit?html,js,output

Also since ArrayController is/will be depreciated from v1.13 is there alternative way of doing this without using ArrayController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated emberjsbin of what I think you're looking for -

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qujihihivi/edit?html,js,output

---

- ArrayController vs. ObjectController doesn't matter anymore, you can just use Ember.Controller.extend as you'll see in the updated bin.
- I did the sorting in the model by creating an Ember Array for the model and tagging the `.sortBy("index")` onto it.
- I also updated the templates with new syntax, you don't need `{{bind-attr}}` anymore and you should use `{{#each itemCollection as |item|}}` instead of just `{{#each itemCollection}}`, makes for easier to read templates and provides consistent scope.

Hope the updated bin is helpful!